# How to display a text with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot-annotations

I would like to do this :

I have this python code :

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
b = np.array([7,8,6,3,2,1,5,8,4,15])
c = plt.plot(a,b,'.')
d = 5
plt.text(2,3, "d = "+d) #This line is the problem because i have not the value of d !
plt.show()
```

So actually I just want to display the value of d and also I want to display the value of d but relatively for instance at the bottom right but not with some coordinates. Is it possible to do this with Python ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [`transform`](http://matplotlib.org/api/transformations.html#matplotlib.transforms.Transform) argument to place in relative coordinates from `0.0` to `1.0` for example

```
plt.text(0.5,
         0.67,
         "d = {}".format(d),
         transform=plt.gca().transAxes)
```

In this local system `(0, 0)` is the lower-left and `(1, 1)` is the upper-right of the plot. [Here is a good reference](http://matplotlib.org/users/text_props.html) for placing and rotating text at various locations on the plot.

Answer (score 9):

#### text

You can use [`text`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text) to place a text in the figure. By default, the coordinates are data coordinates, but you can specify a transform to switch e.g. to axes coordinates.

```
plt.text(.96,.94,"d={}".format(d), bbox={'facecolor':'w','pad':5},
         ha="right", va="top", transform=plt.gca().transAxes )
```

#### annotate

You can use [`annotate`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate) to produce a text somewhere in the figure. The advantage compared to `text` is that you may (a) use an additional arrow to point to an object, and (b) that you may specify the coordinate system in terms of a simple string, instead of a transform.

```
plt.annotate("d={}".format(d), xy=(p, 15), xytext=(.96,.94), 
            xycoords="data", textcoords="axes fraction",
            bbox={'facecolor':'w','pad':5}, ha="right", va="top")
```

#### AnchoredText

You can use an [`AnchoredText`](https://matplotlib.org/api/offsetbox_api.html#matplotlib.offsetbox.AnchoredText) from offsetbox:

```
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnchoredText
a = AnchoredText("d={}".format(d), loc=1, pad=0.4, borderpad=0.5)
plt.gca().add_artist(a)
```